# How to delete row from excel sheet using command button and listbox selection

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, commandbutton

I have written the following code to delete a row from an excel table, and update the listbox when i click a commandbutton("Delete").

the code executes and says "row deleted successfully." but the data is not actually removed from the excel table or the listbox.

The code i am using is:

'Delete Function to remove row from Excel Table and Listbox

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton29_Click()

    Dim ws7 As Worksheet

    Dim foundCell As Range

    Dim searchvalue As Variant
    
    searchvalue = ListBox4.Value
    
    Set ws7 = worksheets(7)
    
    ' Find the cell with the search value in column A
    Set foundCell = ws7.Columns(1).Find(searchvalue)

    ' Check if the value was found
    If foundCell = searchvalue Then
        ' Delete the entire row of the found cell
        foundCell.EntireRow.Delete
        MsgBox "Row deleted successfully.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

any help is greatly appreciated. I just started self learning programming a month ago.

I tried modifying the code a few ways with no success

Comment: `ListBox1.Value` is `Null` if users doesn't select any items in ListBox. `foundCell` will be a blank cell. `foundCell.EntireRow.Delete` doesn't change anything. Check it with `Debug.Print searchvalue`

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like there might be an issue with the way you are checking if the value was found. The Find method returns a Range object, not a single value. You should use the `Not foundCell Is Nothing` condition to check if the value was found.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I tried this and i get the same results as before. msg box says row was deleted but nothing actually gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton29_Click()

    Dim ws7 As Worksheet

    Dim foundCell As Range

    Dim searchvalue As Variant


    searchvalue = ListBox4.Value

    Set ws7 = Worksheets(7)

    ' Find the cell with the search value in column A

    Set foundCell = ws7.Columns(1).Find(searchvalue)

    ' Check if the value was found

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

        ' Delete the entire row of the found cell

        foundCell.EntireRow.Delete

        MsgBox "Row deleted successfully.", vbInformation
    Else

        MsgBox "Value not found.", vbExclamation

    End If
End Sub
```